# How to Apply Path of Video Player & Video File in nopcommerce?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am working on video module & i want to play flash video.

for that i have uploaded file in AppData/FlashFile folder and player in AppData/player folder.

I have written following code to access video player  video file.

```
   string playerpath = "~/App_Data/player/player/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf";
   string path = "~/App_Data/Flashfiles/" + item.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();

 <object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="@playerpath" name="fp_97432156_api" id="fp_97432156_api">
                            <param value="true" name="allowfullscreen">
                            <param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
                            <param value="high" name="quality">
                            <param value="#000000" name="bgcolor">
                            <param value="opaque" name="wmode">
                            <param value="config={&quot;plugins&quot;:{&quot;controls&quot;:{&quot;volume&quot;:false}},&quot;playerId&quot;:&quot;fp_97432156&quot;,&quot;clip&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;'@path'&quot;},&quot;playlist&quot;:[{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;'@path'&quot;}]}" name="flashvars">
                        </object>
```

But it doesn't display video.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: is this aspx page or html page?

Answer (score 0):

put `Literal` control as below

now you can add the player from code behind

```
var objstr = @"<object width=""100%"" height=""100%"" type=""application/x-shockwave-flash"" data=""{0}"" name=""fp_97432156_api"" id=""fp_97432156_api"">
   <param value=""true"" name=""allowfullscreen"">
   <param value=""always"" name=""allowscriptaccess"">
   <param value=""high"" name=""quality"">
   <param value=""#000000"" name=""bgcolor"">
   <param value=""opaque"" name=""wmode"">
   <param value=""config={&quot;plugins&quot;:{&quot;controls&quot;:{&quot;volume&quot;:false}},&quot;playerId&quot;:&quot;fp_97432156&quot;,&quot;clip&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;'@path'&quot;},&quot;playlist&quot;:[{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;'{1}'&quot;}]}"" name=""flashvars"">
</object>";

PlayerObject.Text = string.Format(objstr, playerpath ,path);
```